# Using CORS enabled ASP.NET Web API 2 running on localhost, I could do GET and POST requests but not PUT and DELETE requests

Tags: jquery, ajax, asp.net-web-api, cors

[image]

The red "NetworkError:..." messages are from PUT and DELETE requests. Anyone have any immediate idea why this is the case? My web.config is already configured for CORS like so:

```
<httpProtocol>
      <customHeaders>
        <remove name="X-Powered-By" />
        <add name="Access-Control-Allow-Origin" value="*" />
        <add name="Access-Control-Allow-Headers" value="Content-Type" />
        <add name="Access-Control-Allow-Methods" value="GET, POST, PUT, DELETE, OPTIONS" />
      </customHeaders>
</httpProtocol>
```

My Web API Controller, using Entity Framework and MSSQL:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Net;
using System.Net.Http;
using System.Web.Http;
using System.Web.Http.Cors;

namespace CarsoWebApiTraining.Controllers
{
    [EnableCors("*", "*", "*")]
    public class StudentController : ApiController
    {
        GeneralEntities entity = new GeneralEntities();

        StudentController()
        {
            entity.Configuration.LazyLoadingEnabled = false;
        }

        // GET: api/Student
        public IEnumerable<Student> Get()
        {

            return entity.Students;
        }

        // GET: api/Student/5
        public Student Get(int id)
        {
            try
            {
                entity.Students.Where(p => p.StudentID == id).FirstOrDefault();
            }

            catch 
            {
            }

            return entity.Students.Where(p => p.StudentID == id).FirstOrDefault();
        }

        // POST: api/Student
        public void Post([FromBody]Student student)
        {
            entity.Students.Add(student);
            entity.SaveChanges();
        }

        // PUT: api/Student/5
        public void Put(int id, [FromBody]Student student)
        {
            Student selectedStudent = Get(id);
            selectedStudent.Name = student.Name;
            selectedStudent.ICNo = student.ICNo;

            entity.SaveChanges();
        }

        // DELETE: api/Student/5
        public void Delete(int id)
        {
            entity.Students.Remove(Get(id));
            entity.SaveChanges();

        }


    }
}
```

Comment: Show us your web api controller

Comment: Are you using IIS as web server? If so, make sure that WebDAV Publishing is not installed. To do so: Windows Features > Internet Information Services > World Wide Web Services > Common HTTP Features > WebDAV Publishing

Comment: @CharlesOuellet Or remove the WebDav handler in the web.config file.

Answer (score 0):

This is what I found. This [link](http://brockallen.com/2012/10/18/cors-iis-and-webdav/) might help you in finding the cause. You can check in your hosting environment whether these verbs are allowed or not.

> ```
> The other common problem when using the CORS support from 
> Thnktecture.IdentityModel is that the handler for .NET code (the ExtensionlessUrlHandler) 
> by default only allows GET, POST, HEAD and DEBUG methods.
> ```

Comment: This answer is not valid as @Geoyws is not using CORS support from Thinktecture.IdentityModel, but CORS support from System.Web.Http.Cors.